# hibernate java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer

Tags: java, hibernate

When I tried to build my first hibernate application the following error occurs `NoClassDefFoundError`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer
    at org.hibernate.search.impl.ConfigContext.initAnalyzer(ConfigContext.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.search.impl.ConfigContext.<init>(ConfigContext.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchFactoryBuilder.initDocumentBuilders(SearchFactoryBuilder.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchFactoryBuilder.buildNewSearchFactory(SearchFactoryBuilder.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.search.spi.SearchFactoryBuilder.buildSearchFactory(SearchFactoryBuilder.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.sessionFactoryCreated(HibernateSearchSessionFactoryObserver.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:587)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at com.TestHibrnt.main(TestHibrnt.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: if my answer is helpful you can select my answer below down arrow in my answer click on right sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Required `jar` containing `org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer` is missing so you have to [download jar(lucene-1.2.jar)](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/l/Downloadlucene12jar.htm) and then set your `classpath`

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer overrides final method tokenStream.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/Reader;)Lorg/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenStream;

Comment: in your classpath there may be 2 jar with same name...(lucene)

Comment: I use lucene-7.1 library. So my code does not work with lucene-1.2 which is old.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today. When I check the error, I found `org.hibernate.search` on several lines, even though I'm just using the Hibernate ORM. Then I removed the build path of Hibernate Search and no more error. Check if you have the same path and if you don't need it, just remove it.